# Javaのpublic static void main(String[] args)におけるvoidとmainの関係について

Tags: java

プログラミング初心者です。

Javaの勉強を開始すると、はじめに目にするpublic static void main(String[] args)という一文ですが、戻り値を返さないvoidと、return文で戻り値を返すmainメソッドをなぜ同時に使っているかがわかりません。

ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

`public static void main(String[])` は `return` で値を返すことはできません。そのようなコードを書くとコンパイルエラーになります。

何かの参考文書にそういったコードがあるなら、それは文書の間違いか読み間違いだと思われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。下の方の回答にあるように、戻り値を返せるものはint main()であるにもかかわらず、main()だけで返せると勘違いしていました。

Answer (score 2):

戻り値が必要なときには
int main(...)
を使い、
戻り値が不要な場合には
void main(...)
を使う、そんだけのはなしです

で、この２つは同時には使えません。

＃って回答でいいのかな？

Comment: 戻り値を返せるものはint main()であるにもかかわらず、main()だけで返せると勘違いしていました。int main()とvoid main()の区別はしっかりと理解したいと思います！

Answer (score 1):

参考までにmainでOSに対して結果を返す場合はSystem.exit(値);で処理を終えることにより正常終了／異常終了などをOSが実行結果として判定できます。